# MSAccess - Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method - While trying to open file

Tags: ms-access, compiler-errors

I am trying to work around an old MS ACCESS DB and have no idea of MSAccess can someone help me with the below code ?

```
Private Sub Cmd_Directory_Click()
Dim Filename1, MyFile, RowSrc, Ext As String
Dim MyPos, MyPos1, Length, Dist As Integer
         'Set filters.
        cmDialog1.DialogTitle = "Select the FWD Data Directory"
        cmDialog1.Filters = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|ROAR Header Files (*.hea)|*.hea|"
        'Specify default filter.
        cmDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
        'Display the File Open dialog box.
        cmDialog1.ShowOpen
        Filename1 = cmDialog1.FileName
       If Filename1 = "" Then
       End
       End If
'Filter out the directory
       MyPos1 = 0 'Start after C:\
       Do 'Looping to find last \ in long file names
       MyPos = MyPos1 + 1
       MyPos1 = InStr(MyPos, Filename1, "\", 1)
       Length = MyPos1 - MyPos
       Loop Until MyPos1 = 0
       Length = Len(Filename1)
       Dist = Length - MyPos + 1
       'Get the filename from the file
       'Me!FileName = Left((Right(Filename1, dist)), dist - 4)
       Me.ROARDirectory = Left(Filename1, MyPos - 2)
'Add avalible FWD Files
 
'Get the file extension selected
    If cmDialog1.FilterIndex = 2 Then
        Ext = "\*.hea"
    Else
    End If
 
 
    MyFile = Dir(Me.ROARDirectory & Ext)
    RowSrc = ""
    Do
    Length = Len(MyFile)
    Length = Length - 4
    MyFile = Left(MyFile, Length)
    RowSrc = RowSrc & MyFile & ";"
    ListBox1.RowSource = RowSrc
    MyFile = Dir
    Loop Until MyFile = ""
    
End Sub

Private Sub Cmd_LengthDiscrepancyROARList_Click()

'Views the ROAR Remaining Survey List
  
Forms![frmStartup]!TxtSurveyList.Value = "ROARLengthDiscrepancy"
  
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ProjectSurveyList", acViewPreview

End Sub
```

Its giving me below error which I have no idea how to fix.
The error is thrown when I try to click on browse to a file and it does not allow me to access any file simply throws this error.

[image: Error]

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: And that happens on which code line?

Comment: Not showing cmDialog object declared and set.

Comment: Error is on ```cmDialog1.DialogTitle = "Select the FWD Data Directory"```